# Integration of PDF

Tags: probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be random variables. I need to find $Y$ conditional probability density function, when:

a) $f_{xy}(x,y)=\lambda^2exp(-\lambda y)$, $0\leq x\leq y< \infty$

b) $f_{xy}(x,y)=x exp(-x(y+1))$, $x,y \geq 0$

My question is about interval of integration. For **b)** part interval should be 
$[0,\infty]$:

($f_x(x)=\int_{0}^{\infty}x exp(-x(y+1))dy \Longrightarrow f(y|x)=\frac{f(x,y)}{f_x(x)}$), right?

How about part **a)** ?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain in a) is $0\leq x \leq y < \infty$, meaning that $x \leq y < \infty$ so $y \in [x, \infty)$. Thus, the limits of integration are $x$ and $\infty$:

$$
f_X(x)=\int_x^\infty f_{X, Y}(x, y) dy
$$

Comment: Got it! Thank you for help.